# How to place chart created in code behind into aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, webforms

I created a chart and used it inside mvc. It works  as i only need to call the action inside the views but now im trying to place it inside an aspx page and created upon button click. Please help. P.s Ive just started learning on c# and aspx. Tqvm in advanced.

```
public void graphClck(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CodeDB2 DB = new CodeDB2();
        DB.Open();
        DataTable data = DB.GetTable("SELECT * FROM tblproduct");
        DB.Close();
        //Chart c = new Chart(width: 800, height: 200);

        Chart c = new Chart(width: 800, height: 200)
            .AddTitle("PRODUCT")
            .AddSeries(
            chartType: "column",
            name: "Products",
            xValue: data.AsDataView(), xField: "product_name",
            yValues: data.AsDataView(), yFields: "quantity")
            .AddSeries(
            name: "Price",
            yValues: data.AsDataView(), yFields: "price")
            .AddLegend("PRODUCT PRICE AND QUANTITY")
            .Write("png");
}
```

in my aspx design page

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="GraphButton" Text="Produce Graph" OnClick="graphClck"/>   
        <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server"></asp:Chart>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your "Chart" is Control, just use method
[myChart.DrawToBitmap();](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap(v=vs.110).aspx)
and set this bitmap to client view just like Bitmap

Comment: can you elaborate more on this? im still a student so im not familiar with this. Thank you again for helping.

Comment: Think, your actual question now is "how to set bitmap" on page element from server-side code. Then, make a bitmap from "chart" and set it like a simple dynamic png/jpg

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set the properties of the chart control rather than building the chart dynamically.

So instead of `.AddTitle` you would use Chart1.AddTitle("Title Here").

You would follow the same approach for the other properties.

SAMPLE
This is a sample of how I have used it in the past

```
 List<DAL.QuoteChartData> QuoteChartData = DAL.GetQuotesChart(SessionStore.Current.UserID, StartDate, EndDate);

        if (QuoteChartData.Count > 0)
        {
            //Populate Summary Chart
            chrtQuoteSummary.Legends.Add("Legend1");
            chrtQuoteSummary.Legends["Legend1"].Docking = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Docking.Bottom;

            chrtQuoteSummary.Series["Quotes"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
            chrtQuoteSummary.Series["Quotes"].Legend = "Legend1";
            chrtQuoteSummary.Series["Quotes"].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Doughnut;

            QuoteChartData.ForEach(delegate (DAL.QuoteChartData R)
            {
                chrtQuoteSummary.Series["Quotes"].Points.Add(new System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint() { AxisLabel = R.QuoteStatus, YValues = new double[] { double.Parse(R.Tot.ToString()) } });
                chrtQuoteSummary.Series["Quotes"].Points[chrtQuoteSummary.Series["Quotes"].Points.Count - 1].Color = Global.StatusColours[R.QuoteStatusID.ToString()];
            });
        }
        else
        {
            lblQuotesMsg.Text = "No quote data found for the current month.";
        }
```